# VLC Record a corrupt videofile from RTSP stream (Every 30 minute timer)

Tags: timer, vlc, rtsp

I've prescribed everything that I need, the recording goes natively from the camera without video file parameters (the video file is saved normally when VLC is closed by clicking the cross). But when the process is closed manually from the script, the recording remains corrupted. I'm trying to figure out what it could be connected with.

*** If you want to hear the cool story ***

Dad decided to buy an IP camera to protect our house, I decided to play with it (because the software that comes with this Chinese garbage requires me to pay for cloud service).

I decided to create my own script that satisfied its functions (I and programming are incompatible things).

To be honest, I could record the stream on my Google Drive (good thing the application is embedded in Windows with all the disks). But I decided to record to local disks for now. Since I can always make backups of the necessary recordings.

I modified the script using Chat GPT since I could not record the recording time (in 24 hour format) on the internet. The names are written as I need, i.e. as: 01.01.2001_00.00.

After satisfied with the result I told the bot to record every 30 minutes. It seems to work, but when I finish recording and restart VLC, the video file is saved corrupted.

--stop-time 5 "Works as a restart if the camera loses power or the signal is interrupted"

*** SCRIPT ***

```
@echo off

REM Set the output directory
set "output_directory=D:\VIDEO"

:RECORD
REM Get the current date and time
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ('time /t') do (set mytime=%%a.%%b)

REM Run the VLC command with the current date and time in the filename
START "" "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" rtsp://admin:@192.168.0.102:554/ --loop --stop-time 5 --sout=#duplicate{dst=file{dst=D:\VIDEO\%DATE%_%mytime%.mp4,no-overwrite},dst=display} :no-sout-all :sout-keep --run-time=1800 vlc://quit

REM Wait for 1800 seconds
timeout /t 1800 /nobreak >nul

REM Close VLC
taskkill /f /im vlc.exe

REM Wait for 1 second
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul

REM Go back to recording
goto RECORD
```

The ffmpeg analog is even more convoluted for me and doesn't give a picture when recording. That's why I stick to VLC